# Oracle merge into with text similarlity

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables: from_country and to_country. I want to bring new records and update records to `to_country`

Definition and data

```
--
CREATE TABLE from_country
(
  country_code varchar2(255) not null
);

--
CREATE TABLE to_country
(
  country_code varchar2(255) not null
);

-- Meaning match
INSERT INTO from_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('United States of America');

-- Match 100%
INSERT INTO from_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('UGANDA');

-- Meaning match, but with domain knowledge
INSERT INTO from_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('CON CORRECT');

-- Brand new country
INSERT INTO from_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('NEW');


-- 
INSERT INTO to_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('USA');

-- Match 100%
INSERT INTO to_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('UGANDA');

-- Meaning match, but with domain knowledge
INSERT INTO to_country
(country_code)
VALUES
('CON');
```

I need to run merge into so I bring data from `from_county` to `to_country`

Here is my 1st attempt, but it only does a equal, which is not good enough. I need some smartness so that it is able to do meaning match.
If anyone know how to do it, please provide your solution.

```
merge into 
  to_country to_t
using
  from_country from_t
on
  (to_t.country_code = from_t.country_code)
when not matched then insert (
  country_code
)
values (
  from_t.country_code
);
```

So in a nutshell, here is what I want

```
from_table:
United States of America
UGANDA
CON CORRECT
NEW


to_table:
USA
UGANDA
CON
```

After oracle merge into

```
the new to_country table:
United States of America
UGANDA
CON CORRECT
NEW
```

sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f512d

Please note that this is my simplified example. I have larger data set.

Answer (score 1):

Since the match is not guaranteed unique, you have to write a query that will return only one match using some decision.

Here is a simplified case which uses a naive match and then just picks one value when there is more than one match:

```
merge into to_country t
using (
  select * from (
    select t.rowid as trowid
          ,f.country_code as fcode
          ,t.country_code as tcode
          ,case when t.country_code is null then 1 else
             row_number()
             over (partition by t.country_code
                   order by f.country_code)
           end as match_no
    from from_country f
    left join to_country t
    on f.country_code like t.country_code || '%'
  ) where match_no = 1
  ) s
on (s.trowid = t.rowid)
when matched then update set country_code = s.fcode
when not matched then insert (country_code) values (s.fcode);
```

Result in to_country:

```
USA
UGANDA
CON CORRECT
United States of America
```

Now that that's taken care of, you just need to make the match algorithm smarter. This is where you need to look at the whole dataset to see what sort of errors there are - i.e. typos, etc.

You could try some of the procedures in Oracle's supplied **UTL_MATCH** for this purpose: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_match.htm - such as EDIT_DISTANCE, or JARO_WINKLER.

Here is an example using the Jaro Winkler algorithm:

```
merge into to_country t
using (
  select * from (
    select t.rowid as trowid
          ,f.country_code as fcode
          ,t.country_code as tcode
          ,case when t.country_code is null then 1
           else row_number() over (
                partition by t.country_code
                order by utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(f.country_code,t.country_code) desc)
           end as match_no
    from from_country f
    left join to_country t
    on utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(f.country_code,t.country_code) > 70
  ) where match_no = 1
  ) s
on (s.trowid = t.rowid)
when matched then update set country_code = s.fcode
when not matched then insert (country_code) values (s.fcode);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f512d/23

Note that I've picked an arbitrary cutoff of >70%. This is because UGANDA vs. USA has a Jaro Winkler similarity of 70.

This results in the following:

```
United States of America
USA
UGANDA
CON NEW
```

To see how these algorithms fare, run something like this:

```
select f.country_code as fcode
      ,t.country_code as tcode
      ,utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(f.country_code,t.country_code) as ed
      ,utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(f.country_code,t.country_code) as jw
from from_country f
cross join to_country t
order by 2, 4 desc;

FCODE                     TCODE    ED   JW
========================  ======  ===  ===
CON NEW                   CON      43   86
CON CORRECT               CON      28   83
UGANDA                    CON      17   50
United States of America  CON       0    0

UGANDA                    UGANDA  100  100
United States of America  UGANDA    9   46
CON NEW                   UGANDA   15   43
CON CORRECT               UGANDA    0   41

UGANDA                    USA      34   70
United States of America  USA      13   62
CON CORRECT               USA       0    0
CON NEW                   USA       0    0
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f512d/22